# How to disable TfsComProviderSvr.exe?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, team-foundation-server

My Explorer.exe in Windows 10 is freezing too often. As TfsComProviderSvr.exe is often at high CPU usage when this happens, I suspect this process is causing it. So, I want to switch it off.

How to switch TfsComProviderSvr.exe off The Right Way? I can rename the file, but there is probably a more elegant way to do so.

Comment: are you using powershell to connect to TFS at the time it is freezing?

Comment: do you use Team Foundation server? if not, uninstall it completely in control panel->settings app->apps

Answer (score 2):

I created a shortcut and added the below command in Target. I use this shortcut to kill the TfsComProviderSvr.exe whenever I see large number of instances running.

C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe /f /fi "imagename eq TfsComProviderSvr.exe"

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened to me as well. I did kill the process (`TfsComProviderSvr.exe`) from task manager but it restarts itself automatically.

However, the high CPU usage and WinExplorer'hangging disappeared and my computer came back to normal.

I did a search but couldn't find a better solution, so just kill it, man!